# create and display a powershell object with 2 columns with 15 lines from a file .txt

Tags: powershell

I want to create and display a powershell object with two columns (two properties: `np` and `date`) with 15 lines from a file "test.txt".

```
1   21/05/20
2   21/05/20
3   21/05/20
4   21/05/20
5   21/05/20
6   21/05/20
7   21/05/20
8   21/05/20
9   21/05/20
10  21/05/20
11  21/05/20
12  21/05/20
13  21/05/20
14  21/05/20
15  21/05/20
```

Here is my code:

```
$path1="C:\content1\test.txt"
$tableau = Get-Content $path1

Foreach($valeur in $tableau) {
    # trim spaces at beginning and end
    
    $valeur = $valeur.trim() 
    
    # insert , at specific places for ConvertFrom-CSV command
    
    $valeur = $valeur.insert(2,",")
    
    $valeur = $valeur -replace "\s+",""
    $Object = $valeur | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'np', 'date'      
}  

$Object
```

The output of my code is:

```
np date
-- ----
15 21/05/20
```

I have only the last line in my object `$Object` whereas I want the 15 lines of my .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly assign the output of `foreach` to variable `$object` like this:

```
$path1="C:\content1\test.txt"
$tableau = Get-Content $path1

$object = Foreach($valeur in $tableau) {
    # trim spaces at beginning and end
    
    $valeur = $valeur.trim() 
    
    # insert , at specific places for ConvertFrom-CSV command
    
    $valeur = $valeur.insert(2,",")
    
    $valeur = $valeur -replace "\s+",""
    $valeur | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'np', 'date'      
}
```

Looks strange, but it is a common pattern in PowerShell (e. g. you can also assign from output of other control blocks like `if` and `switch`).

This works similar to assigning output of a pipeline to a variable. The output of `ConvertFrom-Csv` gets captured automatically and added to the array that PowerShell builds up and finally assigns to `$object`.

Answer (score 1):

In each turn of the foreach-loop you set `$Object`, thus overwriting the previous value.

Move the last line inside the loop and you will get the values.

```
$path1="C:\content1\test.txt"
$tableau =Get-Content $path1

Foreach($valeur in $tableau){ # trim spaces at beginning and end

$valeur= $valeur.trim() 
 
# insert , at specific places for ConvertFrom-CSV command

$valeur=$valeur.insert(2,",")
  
  $valeur=$valeur -replace "\s+",""
  $Object =$valeur | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'np', 'date'
$Object
}
```

Comment: Although this outputs the lines correctly, OP wants the result in `$Object`.

Comment: Zett42 is right, this outputs the lines correctly but the result in not in $object and this is the goal of the question

Answer (score 0):

How about just this...

```
$RecordList = (Get-Content 'D:\Temp\TestFile.txt'| 
Select-Object -First 16) -replace "\s+","," | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header np, date
# Results
<#
np date    
-- ----    
1  21/05/20
2  21/05/20
3  21/05/20
...
#>

 $RecordList.np
# Results
<#
1
2
3
...
#>

 $RecordList.date
 # Results
<#
21/05/20
21/05/20
21/05/20
...
#>

Or

(Get-Content 'D:\Temp\TestFile.txt'| 
Select-Object -First 16) -replace "\s+","," | 
ForEach {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        np   = ($PSItem -split ',')[0]
        date = ($PSItem -split ',')[1]
    }

}
# Results
<#
np date    
-- ----    
1  21/05/20
2  21/05/20
3  21/05/20
...
#>
```

Comment: thanks! I will try this too!!very very useful!

Comment: No worries, PS always provides multiple ways to get stuff done.